# Как массово обновить записи БД с помощью yii2 ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Всем привет. У меня есть 2 таблицы, расположенные в РАЗНЫХ БД:

```
requests

id | user_id | comment

users

id | name | client_id
```

В каждой примерно 20 тысяч строк.

Мне нужно взять данные из поля `comment` таблицы `requests`, найти соответствующие им `client_id` в таблице `users` (`requests`.`comment` = `users`.`id`). Из этих соответствующих данных взять `users`.`client_id` и записать их в `requests`.`comment`. Как это можно сделать с помощью ActiveRecord?

Мой код:

```
class CodeController
{
    public function actionGo()
    {

        $commentsFromUsers = Requests::find()
            ->select('comment')
            ->column();

        $users = Users::find()
            ->where(['id' => $commentsFromUsers])
            ->all();

        foreach($users as $user){
            $request = Requests::find()
                ->where(['comment' => $user->id])
                ->one();

            $request->comment = $user->client_id;
            $request->update();
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код работает, но ОЧЕНЬ долго, и я понимаю, что делать так много обращений к БД неправильно. Может быть, можно обновить данные с помощью ActiveRecord одним запросом? Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении искать решение задачи.

Comment: *Может быть, можно обновить данные с помощью ActiveRecord одним запросом?* решение на RawSQL устроит?

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответ! Хотелось бы сделать всё через ActiveRecord. Но буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: *Хотелось бы сделать всё через ActiveRecord.* Я в уях ничего не понимаю, но по смыслу перевода ActiveRecord - это "активная запись". То есть ОДНА ЗАПИСЬ. А потому при использовании её тебе и приходится заниматься итерацией, обновляя по одной записи, пока не обновятся все. А вот SQL-запросу на всякие там клиентские фокусы (в смысле, фокус на записи. а не фортели) чхать с высокой колокольни, он единым махом обновит всё, что соответствует условиям отбора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне нужно взять данные из поля `comment` таблицы `requests`, найти соответствующие им `client_id` в таблице `users` (`requests.comment = users.id`). Из этих соответствующих данных взять `users.client_id` и записать их в `requests.comment`.

В формате Raw SQL это выглядит так:

```
UPDATE requests, users
SET requests.comment = users.client_id
WHERE requests.comment = users.id
```

Правда, само намерение странное. Вызывает большие сомнения необходимость обновления именно того поля, по значению которого устанавливается соответствие - `requests.comment`. Ведь это разваливает связь (хотя и устанавливает связь с той же таблицей по другому полю). И, соответственно, в таблице получаются записи, как связанные по одному полю, так и по другому, и я не вижу в общем способа, как их потом различать.

Comment: Спасибо за запрос!